# Editing data with Server Object Extension?

Tags: arcobjects, editing, server-object-extension

Is it possible to use an interface such as IWorkspaceEdit within an Server Object Extension to create new features or update data in a geodatabse?

Perhaps this can only be done through a managed feature service, but I don't want to expose editing to the client, but rather control it more precisely and programatically in an SOE.

I tried to do this, but I am getting an exception when I try to call ITable:CreateRow() .

For what it is worth, I was able to get an IWorkspaceEdit interface from a map services table, and start editing.